# Debugging Groovy in Jira Scriptrunner inline editor

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm a programmer who is just getting started working with groovy in Jira in order to automate some tasks.

I'm trying to write a custom listener script using the inline editor in Jira, but haven't gotten past trying to get a Hello World program to work.

I don't know if the script is running, and can't see any output, and I really need some help with figuring out how to debug the script, preferably through outputs to some kind of console (or even just by reading the Jira logs if necessary), just so that I can actually start trying to learn how to use this tool.

I'm working with the information [HERE](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.1.7/jira/listeners.html#_custom_listeners) as a general guideline to start learning to work with the inline editor.

For a little more context, you can see another related question that I asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528824/jira-scriptrunner-update-a-parents-field-when-modifying-the-childs-field/46565153#46565153).

I've set the debug level to DEBUG for the event which I'm attaching the listener, as shown in this screenshot, based on the information found [HERE](https://www.adaptavist.com/doco/display/SFJ/Set+logging+to+help+debug+your+scripts):
[image: Debug Config]

Here is a screenshot of the inline editor I'm working in in JIRA. In this screenshot, I'm just trying to output 'Hello', and have just clicked the 'Preview' button:
[image]

As you can see, in the 'Result' tab at the bottom of the screen, there is nothing of interest. The 'Logs' tab is also empty, and the 'Timing' tab just says 'Elapsed: 0 ms CPU time: 0 ms', so it seems like nothing if happening.

If I check the log on the server (in the file catalina.2017-10-13.txt), I see the following output:

```
13-Oct-2017 07:01:50.942 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters A servlet request, to the URI http://somevmserver:8080/rest/scriptrunner-jira/latest/listeners/com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.workflow.listeners.CustomListener/params, contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
13-Oct-2017 07:02:26.740 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-12] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters A servlet request, to the URI http://somevmserver:8080/rest/scriptrunner/latest/canned/com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.common.StaticCompilationChecker, contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
13-Oct-2017 07:02:26.974 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters A servlet request, to the URI http://somevmserver:8080/rest/scriptrunner-jira/latest/listeners/com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.workflow.listeners.CustomListener/preview, contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
```

This output doesn't mean a whole lot to me, but it seems apparent that it's being populated as a result of trying to preview the script.

I'm not getting any errors in the inline editor, and it's really simple code, so I don't think it's that.

The only other information I can include that I think is pertinent is that this is a test instance of Jira cloned from our production environment, and its base URL is still set to the URL of the prod environment. Not sure if that has any bearing, but I'm not really a Jira admin, just the programmer tasked with doing this, so I don't want to go fiddling around where I don't need to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using scriptrunner within jira, you'll need to **import** the logger to use the debugger or to output to the console. This can be done with the following:

```
// Enable debugger
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

def log = Logger.getLogger("com.acme.CreateSubtask")
log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
```

And then, you'll be able to see the logged information using `log.debug "hello"`

Answer (score 0):

To see your debug message "Hello" in the log, you must update a issue in your selected project. The Result, Logs and Timing Tabs at the bottom are useless in this view. Just trigger the Listener with a issue update in your selected project and search your debug message in the atlassian-jira.log file.

**Hint:** To view the Log in the browser you can use this jira app https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.cps.lastLog/server/overview